# Mathematical formula of Vector Refraction?

Tags: modeling, node-editor, procedural, mathematics, vector

The only Vector Refraction formula I could find online is:
\begin{equation}
t = \mu \textbf{i} + \textbf{n}\sqrt{1- \mu^2[1-(\textbf{ni})^2]} - \mu \textbf{n}(\textbf{ni})
\end{equation}
Such that Ratio of Indices of Refraction is: $\mu = \dfrac{n_1}{n_2}$ and Dot Product $\textbf{n}\textbf{i}= n_{\text{x}} i_{\text{x}} + n_{\text{y}}i_{\text{y}}  + n_{\text{z}} i_{\text{z}}$ denotes the dot
(scalar) product of normal vectors $\textbf{n}$ and incident vector $\textbf{i}$.

Is this the formula that was implemented into Blender which is used to find the refracted vector?

- If it's not, then what is? This is the only formula I could find online and it works pretty well too.
- If it is, please check out the following question:

---

I made a mathematical example here and compared it to Blender. And Blender's Vector Refraction didn't output the same refracted vector as the above formula:
[image]
*Figure 1* -
*Description:*
The wall of numbers at the top is my detailed calculation of finding the refracted vector. The 2 sketches at the bottom is the comparison between my output and Blender's output, and they are different.

---

[image]

*Figure 2 - Description:*

- The left screenshot is a (2,2,2) cube before being applied with Vector Refraction node, the corner nearest to your eyes is **i** = <2,2,2> which I intended to apply the formula onto. (Also, the blue cube is the original (1,1,1) cube).
- The right screenshot is after applying **n** = <2,2,0> and μ = nᵢ/nₜ = 1/1.333 = 0.75 into the node. You can see that **i** = <2,2,2> doesn't flip to point in the opposite direction and down, like in my expectation. It only flipped but didn't point down.

What are your thoughts on this?

Thank you. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question about using Blender. I think a lot people will hesitate to dive into this unless you tell more about what you are trying to achieve first.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Thank you! I simply want to know the formula which Blender implemented into its Vector Refraction node. I addressed a formula and asked very clear: "Is this the formula that Blender is using?" . Could you please share how to get my post to attract more attention? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Generally we are simple Blender users here. What formulas are used internally is beyond our knowledge and not the topic of this site. Maybe you try to ask the developers. And since you made it clear, you only want to know the formula, this questionis off-topic here since the goal is to help people with the usage of Blender.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Also Blender is open source software, the beauty of it is you can browse the repository and look directly into the code for first hand knowledge about what algorithms are used

Comment: You should ask [HERE](https://devtalk.blender.org/)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you. I don't know how to read code so I asked for help.

Comment: @Emir Thanks for the help! I've already asked there, posted a question for a day already but received no answer. I don't think the developers care.